# Problems grouping information using the ifelse and case_when functions

Tags: r, database, if-statement, data-structures, statistics

I am trying to group the information contained in each of the Brazilian states into regions.
Initially I checked the distribution of these in each state through the function `table`.

```
table(Dados$Estado)
               ACRE             ALAGOAS 
                574                2184 
              AMAPÁ            AMAZONAS 
                728                2624 
              BAHIA               CEARÁ 
               9818                5694 
   DISTRITO FEDERAL      ESPÍRITO SANTO 
              17497                4289 
              GOIÁS            MARANHÃO 
               5896                2705 
        MATO GROSSO  MATO GROSSO DO SUL 
               2984                2683 
       MINAS GERAIS                PARÁ 
              20858                4714 
            PARAÍBA              PARANÁ 
               3428               10608 
         PERNAMBUCO               PIAUÍ 
               6599                1908 
     RIO DE JANEIRO RIO GRANDE DO NORTE 
              26787                2858 
  RIO GRANDE DO SUL            RONDÔNIA 
              11739                1665 
            RORAIMA      SANTA CATARINA 
                514                7246 
          SÃO PAULO             SERGIPE 
              51701                1693 
          TOCANTINS 
               1209
```

To accomplish what I want, I initially tried using `ifelse` strings as follows below, however, see that when performing the `table` function of the created variable called regions again, which contains the information for each state grouped by regions, it does not present the values correctly, that is, the count should be higher since I am grouping each state in its respective region. I also tried using the `case_when` function of the `dplyr` package, however, the problem persists.

```
Dados$Regioes <- ifelse(Dados$Estado == c("SÃO PAULO","MINAS GERAIS", "ESPÍRITO SANTO", "RIO DE JANEIRO"), "Sudeste",
ifelse(Dados$Estado == c("PARANÁ","SANTA CATARINA", "RIO GRANDE DO SUL"), "Sul",
ifelse(Dados$Estado == c("MATO GROSSO DO SUL", "MATO GROSSO", "GOIÁS","DISTRITO FEDERAL"), "Centro-Oeste",
ifelse(Dados$Estado == c("AMAZONAS", "ACRE", "RONDÔNIA","RORAIMA","PARÁ","TOCANTINS","AMAPÁ"), "Norte",
ifelse(Dados$Estado == c("BAHIA", "SERGIPE", "ALAGOAS","PERNAMBUCO","PARAÍBA","RIO GRANDE DO NORTE","CEARÁ","PIAUÍ","MARANHÃO"), "Nordeste",NA)))))
table(Dados$Regioes)
Centro-Oeste     Nordeste        Norte 
        7338         4052         1707 
     Sudeste          Sul 
       25786         9892
```

```
library(dplyr)
Dados$Regioes <- case_when(
Dados$Estado == c("SÃO PAULO","MINAS GERAIS", "ESPÍRITO SANTO", "RIO DE JANEIRO")~ "Sudeste",
Dados$Estado == c("PARANÁ","SANTA CATARINA", "RIO GRANDE DO SUL")~"Sul",
Dados$Estado == c("MATO GROSSO DO SUL", "MATO GROSSO", "GOIÁS","DISTRITO FEDERAL")~"Centro-Oeste",
Dados$Estado == c("AMAZONAS", "ACRE", "RONDÔNIA","RORAIMA","PARÁ","TOCANTINS","AMAPÁ")~ "Norte",
Dados$Estado == c("BAHIA", "SERGIPE", "ALAGOAS","PERNAMBUCO","PARAÍBA","RIO GRANDE DO NORTE","CEARÁ","PIAUÍ","MARANHÃO")~"Nordeste")
table(Dados$Regioes)
Centro-Oeste     Nordeste        Norte 
        7338         4052         1707 
     Sudeste          Sul 
       25786         9892
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to get what you want using [geobr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geobr/vignettes/intro_to_geobr.html)? It's an R package that provides quick and easy access to official spatial data sets of Brazil.

Comment: If not, it is more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. with easy aces to the example data, to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at this post; [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi Eric! Thanks for the feedback.
I would like to create a new variable called "Regions" which contains the grouped information of the states.
I've never worked with ````geobr````, have you? If so, could you come up with a solution?

Comment: I have not worked with the `geobr` package, I've heard about it. Though you might be interested to explore it. It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it. If you want find a direct solution to your question I suggest to take a look at the `case_when` function form [tag:dplyr] https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html (PS. I cannot access google drive form this workstation ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the process of adding `Regioes` but you also seem to have a problem with the encoding of the character sets within the data. I read your data with the following code:

```
Dados <- read.csv(file.choose(), sep=";", encoding="latin1")
```

Now, create a data frame with state and region:

```
Regioes.df <-  rbind(cbind(Estado= c("SÃO PAULO", "MINAS GERAIS",  "ESPÍRITO SANTO",  "RIO DE JANEIRO"), Regioes=rep("Sudeste", 4)),
                     cbind(Estado=c("PARANÁ", "SANTA CATARINA",  "RIO GRANDE DO SUL"), Regioes=rep("Sul", 3)), 
                     cbind(Estado=c("MATO GROSSO DO SUL", "MATO GROSSO", "GOIÁS","DISTRITO FEDERAL"), Regioes=rep("Centro-Oeste", 4)),
                     cbind(Estado=c("AMAZONAS",  "ACRE",  "RONDÔNIA", "RORAIMA", "PARÁ", "TOCANTINS", "AMAPÁ"), Regioes=rep("Norte", 7)),
                     cbind(Estado=c("BAHIA", "SERGIPE", "ALAGOAS","PERNAMBUCO","PARAÍBA","RIO GRANDE DO NORTE","CEARÁ","PIAUÍ",
                                    "MARANHÃO"), Regioes=rep("Nordeste", 9)))
```

Now merge with your original data and tabulate:

```
Dados.Reg <- merge(Dados, Regioes.df, all=TRUE)
table(Dados.Reg$Estado, Dados.Reg$Regioes, useNA="ifany")

                    # Centro-Oeste Nordeste Norte Sudeste   Sul  <NA>
  # ACRE                           0        0   574       0     0     0
  # ALAGOAS                        0     2184     0       0     0     0
  # AMAPÁ                          0        0   728       0     0     0
  # AMAZONAS                       0        0  2624       0     0     0
  # BAHIA                          0     9818     0       0     0     0
  # CEARÁ                          0     5694     0       0     0     0
  # DISTRITO FEDERAL           17497        0     0       0     0     0
  # ESPÍRITO SANTO                 0        0     0    1030     0  3259   <====
  # GOIÁS                       5896        0     0       0     0     0
  # MARANHÃO                       0     2705     0       0     0     0
  # MATO GROSSO                 2984        0     0       0     0     0
  # MATO GROSSO DO SUL          2683        0     0       0     0     0
  # MINAS GERAIS                   0        0     0    5340     0 15518   <===
  # PARÁ                           0        0  4714       0     0     0
  # PARAÍBA                        0     3428     0       0     0     0
  # PARANÁ                         0        0     0       0 10608     0
  # PERNAMBUCO                     0     6599     0       0     0     0
  # PIAUÍ                          0     1908     0       0     0     0
  # RIO DE JANEIRO                 0        0     0    6666     0 20121   <===
  # RIO GRANDE DO NORTE            0     2858     0       0     0     0
  # RIO GRANDE DO SUL              0        0     0       0 11739     0
  # RONDÔNIA                       0        0  1665       0     0     0
  # RORAIMA                        0        0   514       0     0     0
  # SANTA CATARINA                 0        0     0       0  7246     0
  # SÃO PAULO                      0        0     0   12750     0 38951   <===
  # SERGIPE                        0     1693     0       0     0     0
  # TOCANTINS                      0        0  1209       0     0     0
```

As you can see from the table the rows for four states are not being correctly identified so the region is missing. That is why your tabulations do not match.